# How to animate a div when another div is clicked and how to make the animated div move other elements

Tags: html, css, image, animation

I want to animate a `div` when i press another `div`, but i don't have a clue as to how.

i also want the animated div to move the other elements, instead of just animating over them. When i do it, the `div` animates on top of images directly below. I want it to push them. How do I achieve this. This is what i have so far.

This is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rb2azjtL/1/

In my fiddle, there is an image of a horse. How do I make it so that the div pushes the image down when it is animating.

The other problem that I am faced with is that how do I animate the div, when i click another div. I want to click the blue div below to animate the green div. I have tried many ways but I have been unsuccessful

 Any help is appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="Invisible"> </div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-1244-480-10.jpg" class="this"/>
<div class="thing"></div>
CSS
```

**CSS**

```
    .Invisible {
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0%;
    background-color:green;
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
}

    .Invisible:hover {
            z-index:2;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            background-color:green;
            height:20%;
            width:100%;
            -webkit-animation: Rooms 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
            animation: Rooms 1s;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes Rooms {
            from {height:20%; }
            to {height:60%; }
        }

        /* Standard syntax */
        @keyframes Rooms {
            from {height:20%; }
            to {height:60%;}
        }

    .this {
        position:absolute;
        top:20%;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:50%;
    }
    .thing {
    background-color:blue;
        position:absolute;
        top:80%;
        left:20px;
        height:20px;
        width:20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need `@keyframes` in this example. A simple CSS transition will do.

Also, the div is overlaying because you explicitly set its position to `absolute`. Check [this Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/6jqgzd9e/1/).